# COMO PODRIA DAR ESTA SOLUCION?

Tags: python

Alguien podría ayudarme a solucionar esta inquietud o cómo lo debo hacer ya q inicio con python y me quede parado en este embrollo.

realiza un examen con tres preguntas , el usuario deberá responder si y no y al final otorgar una calificación (la calificación se logra con una variable que inicie en 0 y por cada respuesta positiva incrementa en uno)

intente por medio de este código pero me detiene el uso de los condicionales

```
print('CONTESTA SI O NO EN LAS PREGUNTAS')
R1 = str (input('ESTUDIAS: \r\n')),
R2 = str (input('TRABAJAS: \r\n')),
R3 = str (input('TE DIVIERTES EN TUS RATOS LIBRES: \r\n'))
```

Comment: Lo primero, no necesitas usar `str()` alrededor de `input()`, pues input ya devuelve una cadena. Lo segundo ¿qué problema exactamente es el que has encontrado? ¿No sabes cómo mirar si el usuario respondió "SI"? Basta que hagas `if R1=="SI"` por ejemplo.

Comment: Ese código demuestra muy poco esfuerzo por tu parte, y eso no es bien recibido por la comunidad debido a que no queremos hacerle la tarea a la gente. En que estás trabado? Intentaste algo más?

Comment: Hola dante si intente utilizando una lista,con el método.count al R1 pero no me dio por eso solicite ayuda y explicación.

Comment: Entiendo, pero es importante que nos demuestres ese esfuerzo (por ejemplo, agregando el código que lograste hasta el momento aunque no funcione). Además, nunca dije que no te esforzaras, si no que no lo demuestras. Te recomiendo editar la pregunta agregando lo que dices que intentaste.